# Based on Desargues theorem, how can you prove that there exist 2 triangles which are perspective with a point but not with a line?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I actually proved that there exist 2 triangles which can be perspective with a line but not whith a given point. Now I'm having trouble with the one proving that there exist 2 triangles which are perspective with a point but not with a line.
Thank you

Comment: The Desargues theorems states "Two triangles are in perspective axially if and only if they are in perspective centrally" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem So I don't understand what you proved. Please explain.

Comment: the given question is: prove that exist two triangles who do not satisfy the Desargues theorem.Meaning: find two triangles which: 1) are perspective with a line but not with a given point. 2) are perspective with a given point but not with a line. i need help to prove the second one.

Comment: I am confused: your statement contradicts to the Desargue theorem stating "iff" ... here is my email: zgyorfi@erad.com would you please send to me your proof.

Comment: thats actually not difficult, take for example two triangles that have all their sides parallell.A1B1 \\ A2B2, A1CI\\A2C2 , C1B1\\C2B2, these triangles are perspective with a line l infinite. therefore A1B1 intersects A2B2 at a point M which is incident with this line l infinite. doing the same, B1C1 intersects B2C2 at a point L which is incident with l infinite, A1C1 intersects A2C2 at a point N which also is incident with l infinite. there you have two triangles which are perspective with one line, but not with a given point.

Comment: In your counterexample, you showed that the two triangles _are_ perspective with a point, which happens to be a point on the line at infinity. Of course if you are "given" a particular point and a line, you can always find two triangles that are perspective with one but not with the other--for example, by constructing two triangles perspective with the same line and with a different point.